# Listing tables on a SQL Anywhere using iSQL

Tags: sqlanywhere

Is there a way to list all the tables on a SQL Anywhere using iSQL?

Answer (score 1):

```
select table_name from sys.systab where table_type_str = 'BASE'
```

You can change `'BASE'` to `'VIEW'` to get views, and `'GBL TEMP'` to get global temporary tables.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure is this will work or not, but try this:

```
select TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

I believe this is a database independent way of getting a list of tables.

Comment: SQL Anywhere does not support this syntax.

Comment: That is why I said "not sure".